# How to remove element in ArrayList using JOptionPane?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Array {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> alist = new ArrayList<String>();
        alist.add("student ID   ");
        alist.add("1003 ");
        alist.add("1004 ");
        alist.add("1005 ");
        alist.add("1006 ");
        alist.add("1007 ");
        alist.add("1008 ");
        alist.add("1009 ");
        alist.add("1010 ");
        alist.add("1011 ");
        alist.add("1012 ");

        ArrayList<String> studname = new ArrayList<String>();
        studname.add(" student names");
        studname.add("        MARK BROSOTO");
        studname.add("        ALLISAH HERNANDEZ");
        studname.add("        TRIXIE GAYLAWAN");
        studname.add("        JOSHUA SALITA");
        studname.add("        JUSTINE TRIAMBULO");
        studname.add("         JHANDEL BUCATCAT");
        studname.add("        STEPHEN DALMACIO");
        studname.add("        WILLIAM CLARETE");
        studname.add("        SETH CONDE");
        studname.add("        PATRICK PARULAN");

        String output = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < alist.size(); i++) {
            String array = alist.get(i).toString();
            String array2 = studname.get(i).toString();

            output += array + " " + array2 + "\n";
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
    }
}
```

That is my code so how can I remove element using `JOptionPane` like for instance I want to remove

```
alist.add("1003 "); 
alist.add("1004 ");
```

using `JOptionPane` input dialog.

By the way this is what it looks like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg7Hp.png)

Comment: A `JTable` would be more appropriate. Just highlight the row to delete and then click on a _Delete_ button.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an ActionListener event to the "OK" button and then remove the element from the list.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and add sample code demonstrating how to add an `ActionListener` event to the _OK_ button of a `JOptionPane`.